# Returns "FileNotFoundError", while file is already exists

Tags: image, google-colaboratory

I am working on **TensorFlow**, Converting images into **Numpy** array

When I run the code, returns an error **"FileNotFoundError: No Such File or directory"** as you can see in the below image

[No Such File or directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDF0M.png)

As the file is already exist.

So, I check the path

```
os.path.exists("/content/drive/MyDrive/Dog Vision/train (1)")
```

It returns `True`

Comment: `/content/drive/MyDrive/Dog Vision/train (1)` is not the file you're trying to open...

Comment: No, it was the right file. When I copy and paste the path by default it drive gives "/content/…"

Comment: The image shows a long filename following `.../train (1)/`.

Comment: The path is named with the variable "filename" filename = ["/content/drive/MyDrive/Dog Vision/train (1)/" + fname + ".jpg" for fname in labels_csv['id']]

Comment: I am just slicing with index , filename[42]

Comment: `/content/drive/MyDrive/Dog Vision/train (1)` is a folder. And it's existence doesn't necessarily mean that the file inside folder also exists